# Is "uncollaborative" a word?

Tags: adjectives, antonyms, is-it-a-word

I am describing a process as being antithetical to collaboration.

To clarify, I'm referring to its quality as being "not naturally collaborative", not "actively anti-collaboration"

Is "uncollaborative" a word? Is there a word that isn't a variation of "collaboration" that gets the job done?

Comment: I think we need a bit more precision in the question. Are you looking for something that inherently cannot be achieved in a collaborative fashion? Or a process that's deliberately performed to stymie collaboration? Perhaps an example of something with this property, and a sentence (with a blank for the unknown word).

Comment: I personally would not understand a *"collaborative process"* to mean a process *amenable* to collaboration. I do not think there is a single word that means even that, let alone a single word that means *not conducive to collaboration*. A *collaborative process* is one which does or did involve multiple contributors as a matter of ongoing or historical fact. It doesn't imply anything at all to me about whether the same could have been accomplished by a single individual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Insular** "of the nature of an island" and by extension anything which is naturally isolate (q.v.)

Answer (score 3):

**Independent** strikes me as a good candidate.

Answer (score 3):

***Competitive*** springs to mind, if you really mean *antithetical to collaboration*.

Comment: I edited the question to be clearer. This is a fine word but not the direction I was going in.

Comment: It's not the **only** way to impede collaboration, but it's a time-honored alternative and it usually works pretty well in that respect, anyway. Though there is a price; [as Bateson put it](http://www.scribd.com/doc/46752617/Bateson-Mind-and-Nature), "Adversarial systems are notoriously subject to irrelevant determinism."

Comment: @Samuel: really? this isn't what you're looking for? this is the right answer for the title. You need to clarify further (but don't expect your desired exact concept to have a word for it). What other 'direction' is there? 'Not conducive to collaboration', 'impeding collaboration'? This is not the same as opposite or antithetical to X. You should edit the title too then.

Comment: @Mitch Fine. Post title updated.

Answer (score 2):

non-collaborative is the opposite of collaborative

Comment: http://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Employee-Review-Deutsche-Bank-RVW4939564.htm - one example of the same

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I think it's potentially responsive, since the OP asks if "uncollaborative is a word" while also asking for something not a variant of collaboration.